# How to implement real-time tracking of location in React native?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, real-time

I have an ecommerce website and ecommerce app. We sells different products. What I want to do is like Uber or grab app that can track real time location of the taxi going to my location.

So in my app, every time the delivery boy delivers the product to the customer, the delivery boy will see the exact location and direction of his destination. The same as the customer, he/she can see the exact location of the delivery boy. Is it possible to do in React native app and website?

Comment: It is possible, even [Uber Eats](https://eng.uber.com/ubereats-react-native/) was developed with React Native.

Comment: what specific software or tools should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You'll have to take a look into [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)
and also [react-native-bridge](https://github.com/peggyrayzis/react-native-create-bridge) for the gps tracking.
You should check out [jscoach](https://js.coach/), there you can search for packages that will fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually much easier nowadays, with react-native-maps only, by leveraging the watchPosition observer:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
 position => {
  console.log(position);
  const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
  this.setState({ latitude,longitude
 }, 
 error => console.log(error),
 { 
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 20000,
   maximumAge: 1000,
   distanceFilter: 10
 }
);
```

Here's a great detailed tutorial on how to achieve [location tracking in React Native](https://www.instamobile.io/react-native-tutorials/uber-react-native-geolocation/).